# Disable User Registration email in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress site where i want to create accounts for the user but want to prevent users getting an email confirming there registration. Is there a way or a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 possible solutions for you:

1) It's not for the faint of heart, but if you really want to you could try hacking the pluggables.php file in the includes directory. Keep in mind that updating Wordpress would nuke this.

I suspect it would involve modifying this function:

```
function wp_new_user_notification()
```

You can find it around line 1190 in pluggables.php.

2) Alternatively I know the old version of the Register-Plus plugin, included an option to disable user registration e-mail notifications.

Presumably the newer [Register-Plus-Redux](http://wordpress.org/plugins/register-plus-redux/) still offers similar functionality.

Comment: If one of my suggestions works out for you please take a moment and accept the answer by clicking on the big checkbox in the left side of this answer. You even get some points doing that :)

Comment: As the developer of Register Plus Redux I can second your second option, there is a configurable option to "Do NOT send user an email after they are registered".  I'm not a fan of double negatives, but that option is overriding default WordPress behavior.  Typically a checkbox would enable a feature, but in this case we are disabling something.